# Check if text box is empty or not, then put attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Disable the other textbox if the textbox(4) is filled. I have a multiple text boxes in my div

For instance:
If I put a text in textbox(4), then the textbox(1) will becomes disable. Then if I remove the text in the textbox(4), then the text box for the textbox(1) will becomes enable.

Here is the sample html:

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="form-text-wrapper">
    <div><input type="text" class="form-text" value="" name="text1" id="text1"></div>
    <div><input type="text" class="form-text" value="" name="text2" id="text2"></div>
    <div><input type="text" class="form-text" value="" name="text3" id="text3"></div>
    <div><input type="text" class="form-text" value="" name="text4" id="text4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My code doesn't seems to work, I'm not sure what's wrong with my code.

Here is my js code:

```
$('.main-wrapper').each(function(){
  var name = $('#text4', this).val();
  var disForm = $('#text1');
  if ($(name.length >= 1)) {
    $(disForm, this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  } else {
    $(disForm, this).removeAttr('disabled');
  }
});
```

Please help... Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  //change event handler which gets executd whenever the value of #test4 is chaned
  $('#text4').on('change', function() {
    //find all the input elements under the current .form-text-wrapper and except #test4 and set its disabled status based on #text4's value
    $(this).closest('.form-text-wrapper').find('input').not(this).prop('disabled', this.value.length)
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="form-text-wrapper">
    <div><input type="text" class="form-text" value="" name="text1" id="text1"></div>
    <div><input type="text" class="form-text" value="" name="text2" id="text2"></div>
    <div><input type="text" class="form-text" value="" name="text3" id="text3"></div>
    <div><input type="text" class="form-text" value="" name="text4" id="text4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Arun!

Thank you for simplifying the code. That one is much more cleaner than mine which has too many errors, even though I don't understand (.closest and .prop), will google them now. Thank you! :)

Comment: @AyiieMiguel those are api methods.. which you will be able to find out very easly in http://api.jquery.com

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so a few issues with what you are doing.

Firstly you are needing to execute your code every time one of those text boxes changes. You can wrap that functionality into a function and add it to the change event on each of the textboxes. I have added an example below. NB the example could be alot better than explicitly adding the change to each of the textboxes but I'll leave that for you to do.

Secondly you were executing your comparison for if the length was greater than 0 inside a jquery wrapper ($(name.length >= 1)) -> Don't. I've removed that as well in the code sample.

Thirdly I'm a little confused by the requirement. Are you wanting it to toggle disabled/not disabled for just the first text box? REading your code that's what it looked like you were trying to achieve. If you are wanting to disable all of the rest of the text boxes then Arun P Johny's function will do what you want.

```
function onTextChange(){
    console.log('running');
    $('.main-wrapper').each(function(){
      var name = $('#text4', this).val();
      var disForm = $('#text1');
      if (name.length >= 1) {
        $(disForm, this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      } else {
        $(disForm, this).removeAttr('disabled');
      }
    });
}

$('#text1').on('change', onTextChange);
$('#text2').on('change', onTextChange);
$('#text3').on('change', onTextChange);
$('#text4').on('change', onTextChange);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jtgs5kcj/1/

Comment: Hi Dave,

Thank you so much for clearing up everything! I think, Arun's code is what I'm looking for. Thank you again :)